# PSQL cannot login with -h option

Tags: 16.04, postgresql

I can login with psql if I don't use -h option and failed with -h (neither localhost or 127.0.0.1 works). Don't know what's wrong :(

Info: postgresql 10, ubuntu 16.04 on Windows 10.

This is my pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

and my console logs

```
(meta--fVnbZtTA) root@Deathwing:/mnt/d/xx.us/meta-# psql -U meta -W
Password for user meta:
psql (10.2 (Ubuntu 10.2-1.pgdg16.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

meta=> \q
(meta--fVnbZtTA) root@Deathwing:/mnt/d/xx.us/meta-# psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U meta -W
Password for user meta:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "meta"

(meta--fVnbZtTA) root@Deathwing:/mnt/d/xx.us/meta-# psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U meta
Password for user meta:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "meta"
```

Comment: The results do no match the pg_hba.conf rules. Are you sure the postgres service has been reloaded after editing pg_hba.conf? If yes, please add the results without the `-W` option.

Comment: @DanielVérité I'm pretty sure the config is loaded because I've been trying to fix this for days by restarting server and what not. Anyways I've added the result with -W

Answer (score 0):

This invocation:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U meta
```

should match this line in pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

because the lines are tested in the order of the file and it stops at the first match (a match being on `TYPE+DATABASE+USERNAME+[CIDR unless TYPE=local]`, and that combination is the first match for the above invocation.

`trust` means that no password will be requested by the server, but what actually happens per your question is that a password is requested, so there's a contradiction between what you get and your pg_hba.conf

Maybe you're not editing `pg_hba.conf` at the right place. Since version 10, postgresql has a view that reflects the file contents, see

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/view-pg-hba-file-rules.html

> This view can be helpful for checking whether planned changes in the
>   authentication configuration file will work, or for diagnosing a
>   previous failure. Note that this view reports on the current contents
>   of the file, not on what was last loaded by the server.

You might check with `select * from pg_hba_file_rules order by line_number;`
whether the contents are what you expect.

Also `show hba_file` as another SQL command will report where the server finds that file.

Also you need to read the server logs to get additional details about authentication failures, or failure or success to reload the pg_hba.conf file.

On Ubuntu, server logs are under `/var/log/postgresql` unless configured otherwise in `postgresql.conf`